# unable to access all the drives and files in them in java

Tags: java

it displays only the file names of c:\ drive 
its not working in for loop... if i write `list=roots[0].list()` and `list=roots[1].list()`; seperately it works fine. but i need it to work in for loop

```
String list[];

File[] roots = File.listRoots();

System.out.println(roots.length);

for(int i=0;i<roots.length;i++) {
    System.out.println("Root["+i+"]:" + roots[i]);

    list=roots[i].list();

    for( i=0;i<list.length;i++) {
        System.out.println(list[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ever tried debugging? Just stepping through the program while examining the variables gives you the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You use the same looping variable `i` in both loops. That leads to confusion.

Comment: It took me way to long to see that :D

Answer (score 0):

The first problem I see is that you have a set of nested 'for' loops, each using the variable 'i'.

Rather than iterating through the root files, then iterating through the sub-files of each of those, you are going to the first root file. Then iterating through the contents of that one with the same index variable. What I think is happening is that the variable 'i' is then exceeding 'roots.length' and the loop is exiting, try something like this:

```
String[] list;
File[] roots = File.listRoots();
System.out.println(roots.length);
for(int i = 0; i < roots.length; i++)
{
    list = roots[i].list();
    for(int j = 0; j < list.length; j++)
    {
        System.out.println(list[j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Should be `list[j]` then

Comment: Yes it should, this is why I try my best not to use nested loops if I can avoid it, I get the variables mixed up even when trying to explain how to not... :| (Edited)

Answer (score 0):

Use a different increment in your second loop : j for example !

```
String list[];

File[] roots = File.listRoots();

System.out.println(roots.length);

for(int i=0;i<roots.length;i++) {
    System.out.println("Root["+i+"]:" + roots[i]);

    list=roots[i].list();

    for( j=0;j<list.length;j++) {
        System.out.println(list[j]);
    }
}
```